# Whenever I turn my python file into a pyinstaller, pynput key/mouse macro library it doesn't run the commands

Tags: python, pyinstaller, pynput

I'm currently having issues with a program I am making to make it so you can log in to steam with your face using the face_recognition library as well as a keyboard/mouse macro library called pynput. The problem is whenever I try to turn my program from a python file to an exe with pyinstaller, when I try to login the program never runs, here's the code for the log into steam system.

```
def LoginSteam(user, password):
    Keyboard = keyboard.Controller()
    Mouse = mouse.Controller()
    time.sleep(5)
    keyClick(keyboard.Key.cmd, Keyboard)
    time.sleep(5)
    Keyboard.type("steam")
    time.sleep(5)
    keyClick(keyboard.Key.cmd, Keyboard)
    time.sleep(5)
    Keyboard.type(str(user))
    time.sleep(5)
    Mouse.position = (863, 487)
    time.sleep(5)
    mouseClick(mouse.Button.left, Mouse)
    time.sleep(5)
    Keyboard.type(str(password))
    Mouse.position = (871, 545)
    time.sleep(10)
    mouseClick(mouse.Button.left, Mouse)
```

This is the function that takes in the username and password, which are 2 strings that can be found in a dictionary variable called steamaccounts. It first waits 5 seconds, presses the windows key, waits 5 seconds again, types in steam, you get the picture.

The 2 custom functions I wrote will be shown below.

```
def mouseClick(mouseButton, mouse):
    mouse.press(mouseButton)
    mouse.release(mouseButton)

def keyClick(key, keyboard):
    keyboard.press(key)
    keyboard.release(key)
```

These 2 functions take in the keyboard instance, and the key that is being pressed and uses those to make the process of emulating keypresses easier.

Is there a library that works with pyinstaller that can simulate key presses?

Comment: `---hidden-import pynput.keyboard._win32` and `--hidden-import pynput.mouse._win32`

Comment: @gfdweds I have already done that, it still won't execute the macro commands, it only does the Keyboard.type() commands but no windows key is pressed nor is the enter key pressed.